# What does client-optimized mean?

Tags: dart, software-design

Can someone explain what does this phrase mean in this sentence?

> Dart is a **client-optimized** programming language for apps on multiple platforms.

Comment: @NavidShap I agree with you, that definition is confusing. Do someone on Earth advertise their product as a "poorly designed programming language" so that the adjective "optimized" help to understand what Dart really is? If they defined Dart as something like "an optimized client-side programming language" it would sound clearer despite the unnecessary "optimized".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that it is about optimization by the Dart developer (that is, Google).
This means that Google does not optimize Dart for use in applications other than client-oriented applications.
For example, in Dart there is no such thing as RDBMS (Relational Database Management System) and Google does not plan to contribute to this kind of development (to optimize the use of this type).
All software like this is very fragmented and not compatible with each other due to the lack of optimization from the developer’s side.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, dart use a Dart Virtual machine that helps to optimize the code and compile just in time super fast and render or re-render UI very easy, Dart VM works very similar that JVM with Java, Dart Virtual Machine compile your code to low level very fast so if you want to build web apps, mobile apps o desktop apps you will has a full optimized machine code, for Flutter, dart VM compile from Dart to C++, for the web Dart VM compile from dart to Javascript, Dart is a good robust language designed to make very easy characteristics like Hot reload and Hot restart.

Comment: thank you, your answer is useful and gives more detail, but it's hard to find a relation between the question and this answer. but @mezoni gave more clear and simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

A programming language optimised for building user interfaces with features such as the spread operator for expanding collections, and collection if for customising UI for each.

For example spread operator

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
assert(list2.length == 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the "Client" in Client-Optimized is referring to the actual user client, same idea as as Client/Server in web technologies.

Here it refers to the part of the App that is responsible for sending requests to the rest of your App for it to do all the functions you've built it to do.'Client' here includes the front-end parts that the person using your application is interacting with

For many reasons (including the ones mentioned in the other answers), Dart is really well suited to make all things Client run super smoothly. Its Optimized how it renders the UI, the layout, the animations, the load times, how it compiles, etc so everything the user (or "Client") does is Optimized.

As mentioned before, it lacks optimization for things that are not client facing such as database management.